# How to make set property for an array?

Tags: arrays, properties, d

I have:

```
@property float x(float[2] vector)
{
    return vector[0];
}

@property void x(float[2] vector, float value)
{
    vector[0] = value;
}
```

I can declare an array, for example `float[2] a;` and later get the first element of the array by simply calling `a.x`, but if I want to set `a[0]`, I can't call `a.x = 3.14`. It does not cause problems to the compiler nor throws an exception. And later when I get `a[0]` it says it is `NaN` which is `float.init`. This means that a[0] was never set and `a.x` is valid and invalid at the same time.

I simply want a float array and have a get and set property x. Is there a way to do that?
And I know that I can use `a.x(3.14)` for setting `a[0]`, but I want to make it as if `x` is a member property of `a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Static arrays are passed by value. You need to use `ref` to pass by reference:

```
@property float x(ref float[2] vector)
@property void x(ref float[2] vector, float value)
```

Note: I'm referring to D2. AFAIK in D1 static arrays used to be passed by reference, but in D2 they're passed by value by default.